# how can i play mp3 in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

i want to play sound when  my condition is matched, but i don't how can i play sound or music in andengine?

help me to find my solution.

your answer will be awarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obviously use the `MediaPlayer` in `AndEngine` too, it works fine as it does in `Android`, because `AndEngine` is also a part of Android itself.

You can keep your file in `res/raw/anyfile.mp3`

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer
                .create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.anyfile);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

though i haven't perform a sound task, but hope this tutorial link will help u,,

http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html

Comment: this tutoorial for andengine?